# Sorting a paginated list on click in Django

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

What is the best and fast way to sort a paginated list by Spending, Network, Score when clicked on it.

```
                {% autopaginate profiles 20 %}
                {% for profile in profiles %}
                        <div class="columns seven">
                         <h1>Name</h1>
                        </div>                      
                        <div class="columns five">
                            <div class="stats right">                                   
                                <div class="stat">
                                    <h1>{{ profile.spending }}</h1>
                                    <h4>Spending</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="stat">
                                    <h1>{{ profile.network|length }}</h1>
                                    <h4>Network</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="stat">
                                    <h1>{{ profile.score|floatformat:"0"|intcomma }}</h1>
                                    <h4>Score</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                      
                {% endfor %}    
                {% paginate %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use List.js. Take a look at [List.js](http://listjs.com/examples) examples